# QGIS Plugins from Local Source (Firewall excludes Official Repository)

Tags: qgis, plugins

Is there a way to load Plugins From a local Source rather than using the Official Repository. As the authority I work for do not allow QGIS to go past their firewall.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

is to create your own plugins repository. There is documentation about it
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/135896/49538

and here is a full example, [link](https://github.com/All4Gis/CreateQgisRepository)
and that your colleagues add that repository to QGIS on your PCs.

**Another option**

It is to distribute a zip directly to your colleagues and decompress it where Qgis takes the plugins. *.qgis2\python\plugins*

Or as @LaughU says, you can have a shared space and have each colleague have it synchronized with your local QGIS installation.

In the **QGIS 3** version, you can directly import a plugin from a zip, without having to copy it manually.

Hope this helps.