# Defining Custom Path for QGIS3 Plugins

Tags: qgis-plugins, qgis-3, github

Is it possible to add a user-defined path to plugins outside of the standard paths at `%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins` or `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.x\apps\qgis\python\plugins`?

I am working with a team on a git package that *includes* a QGIS3 plugin.  It is highly impractical to develop the plugin outside of the git environment, performing commits, merges, pull, rebases, etc. on a git folder that is not the active plugin and transferring the changes back and forth between there and the plugin folder.  I have not been able to determine how - or *if* - I can set a reference somehow to the path on my computer where the local git files reside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be asking the wrong question or trying to address the problem in a harder way.

The best way I have found to work with a git repository outside the plugins folder and make it update automatically on QGIS fro debugging is to use symbolic links at the operating system level.

Create a symbolic link from your git folder (or only the plugin folder) to the users plugin folder (%UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins).

Here's a good link about creating symbolic links:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Some plugin templates already have tools to create these symbolic links without much trouble.

Then, use the **plugin reloader** plugin to be able to update the plugin without the need to restart QGIS.

https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugin_reloader/

**Warning:** Beware, with a symbolic link, the plugin manager tool will consider it a normal plugin, which means that if you try to uninstall the plugin, it will actually delete files from your original git folder!!

Comment: This seems like a viable option if I can get past the "Access is denied" roadblock.  I am running mklink from an Administrator command prompt but still get the error.  I have tried changing permissions on both the source and target folders to Administrators, to no avail.  Tried it with \D and get "Cannot create a file when that file already exists"

Comment: I believe that, in Windows you need the "mklink /D Link Target" format. Can you share the command you are using? You should have writing permissions on %UserProfile%\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins. After all, that's how plugins are installed.

Comment: you probably have seen this already, but make sure you don't have already a folder with the same name in place.

https://superuser.com/questions/193632/access-is-denied-error-when-i-mklink-on-windows-7/472809#472809

Comment: The existing folder was in the way.  Still had to use the /D to get past the "Access is denied" error, but after removing the folder from the QGIS plugins, the link was successfully created.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a local Plugin Repository in the Plugin Manager's Settings pannel, indicating `file:\path\to\your\root\folder` as URL

I did it two years ago (at work on a NAS drive shared by colleagues) and it worked fine but I don't remember the details.

It need to be zipped if I recall, and there is a **plugins.xml** file to add near the zip.

Here is the xml template  (from [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/135896/104132)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
    <pyqgis_plugin name="SomeName" version="0.1">
        <description>This plugin shows sensitive data</description>
        <homepage>www.gisisfun.com</homepage>
        <qgis_minimum_version>2.2</qgis_minimum_version>
        <file_name>somePlugin.zip</file_name>
        <author_name>YourName</author_name>
        <download_url>http://my-site.com/somePlugin.zip</download_url>
    </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: I considered this option, but it still leaves me having to zip the plugin every time changes are made, and debugging with an IDE (PyCharm, in my case) has to be done on the "copy" and files have to be then transferred back to the git folder for commit, rebase, etc.  It somewhat mitigates - but does not solve - the problem.